# problem in uploading attachment to custom directory

Tags: customization, uploads, attachments, media-library

i have been trying to upload the attachments to the custom directory without affecting the old uploads. so i use this bellow code to achieve that

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'cust_pre_upload');
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'cust_post_upload');

function cust_pre_upload($file){
add_filter('upload_dir', 'cust_dir');
return $file;
}

function cust_post_upload($fileinfo){
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'cust_dir');
return $fileinfo;
}


function cust_dir( $args ) {
$customdir ="/mars";
$args['path'] = "C:/wamp/www/web1/wp-content";
$args['url']  = "http://localhost/web1/wp-content";

$args['subdir']  = $customdir;
$args['path']   .= $customdir; 
$args['url']    .= $customdir;     
return $args;
}
```

i use the wp_handle_upload_prefilter to assign the new directory only for the attachment i upload now or in future and wp_handle_upload to prevent the old attacmments.
this code perfectly uploading to the folder where it supposed to [http://localhost/web1/wp-content/mars/file.jpg but the attachment get this wrong and show an invalid url of the attachment something like this [http://localhost/web1/wp-content/uploads/C:/wamp/www/web1/wp-content/mars/file.jpg]
any help or idea would be appreciated :)
tried different types of codes nothing worked out.

Comment: If you upload a file that has the same name, WordPress won't overwrite the old one. It will still create a new file each time you upload something.

Comment: What happens if you use forward slashes `/` everywhere as you should? `/mars`, `C:/wamp/www/web1/wp-content`. Don’t worry about Windows, it will handle that without problems.

Comment: @toscho already tried with / but no luck still the same prob. its uploading correctly to the specified folder but shows the wrong attachment url as

[http://localhost/web1/wp-content/uploads/C:/wamp/www/web1/wp-content/mars/file.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right you need to `chdir()` into your custom uploads directory (before saving anything there) so that paths are correctly processed and saved in meta.